# firebug dns lookup cache issue

Tags: dns, firebug

This is the screenshot of firebug time line of my site[image: firebug time line]

Why is there a DNS lookup for the images hosted on the same domain as the other content instead of using a cache? I tested this with other site and had no problem there.
((the blue section is the dns lookup time ))
My second question is when to use other hostnames like a.sitename.com and b.sitename.com for increasing pararell downloads? I mean how much bigger should my site be before that trick would increase site loading performance?

Excuse me, my third question is when the DNS lookup costs about 1 second and increases the load time is it true that putting resources like images from another site is a very very bad idea because of load time increase (only for reducing monthly bandwidth of my site)?